# Tem algum problema segurança usar o schema public no PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql

Primeira vez que estou trabalhando com o postgreSQL e estou com essa dúvida se tem algum problema de segurança usar o Schema public que ele cria ? Ou se é só uma questão de organização

Answer (score 1):

Olá!

> A recomendação é criar um único banco de dados com vários esquemas
>   nomeados. Isso é diferente de uma prática comum (e mais antiga) de
>   criar vários bancos de dados e armazenar os objetos dentro do esquema
>   "público". Além disso, recomenda-se remover o esquema público.
>
> Estas são algumas das vantagens de seguir esta recomendação:
>
> - O acesso ao objeto de esquema cruzado é possível a partir de uma única conexão de banco de dados.
> - A concessão de acesso a um esquema é executada por meio de uma instrução GRANT versus uma reconfiguração do arquivo pg_hba.conf.
> - Os esquemas são o padrão ANSI para separação de objetos e espaçamento de nomes.
> - Gerenciando apenas um banco de dados dentro de um único servidor (cluster PostgreSQL).

Mais detalhes [aqui](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Database_Schema_Recommendations_for_an_Application)

Answer (score 1):

Não precisa remover o public, apenas modificar o acesso dos usuários caso tenha mais de um administrador ou usuários com a acesso ao db.

Caso precise restringir de forma organizada os usuários você pode criar outros schemas e colocar o acesso por schema (as tabelas precisam ser realocadas para os outros schemas caso o db já exista), ou seja `grupo A` somente pode acessar o `schema A`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Documentação Oficial: [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/ddl-schemas.html)